sql_variant columns not being read properly in PowerBI, but are read perfectly in Excel
I stole and modified a stored procedure with the intention of it being able to pivot any table if you indicate the static, pivot, and data columns. The thing is not all tables have the same datatypes, so I declared the resulting columns of the pivoted table as sql_variants so it may possibly output the proper data type. I tried pasting the data into excel and it turned out fine (first column was datetime, the rest were int), but when I tried to use the same SQL code as a data source for my direct query PowerBI dashboard, the resulting cells displayed text instead of what I wanted.
I tried loading the data in PowerBI using the import storage method so that I can transform the data, but I'd rather not use that since DirectQuery loads data much easier and faster.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
